# How to repeatedly (forever) animate a BottomNavigationView icon

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I am familiar with BottomNavigationView's on-click one-shot animations. But I have a use case where I need to repeatedly animate BottomNavigationView's icon forever using an XML or vector. I have done enough research but couldn't find a place to start. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: did you tried to make custombottomnavigation of your own to do this?